# ElasticSearch Access-Control-Allow-Headers header is not present

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, elasticsearch, cors

I am making a POST request from a local https server to an ElasticSearch endpoint which has been configured as follows

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Accept
```

The request has headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, Content-Type
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Authorization: (basic authentication token)
```

On a POST request, the following error appears: `Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

The network debugger indeed shows that the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header is not present in the response header. The response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
content-length: 0
date: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 14:08:14 GMT
```

Note that `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is not present and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is blank. All possible string formats have been tested, and these headers do not appear.

Comment: Seems a lot like this issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17483 which has been resolved in 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add following signs to your `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : Authorization, X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length
```

and then restart the es, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem with these config lines in `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/(localhost)?(127.0.0.1)?(:[0-9]+)?/
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length
```

Comment: Can you confirm it was adding the "space" between the COLON and the text? This is present in other answers.

Comment: I think it's typo, should not have space before COLON. I will edit the answer.

Comment: On which of all the nodes you modified the yml?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, according to https://docs.elastic.co/search-ui/tutorials/elasticsearch

try include all headers below

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Accept, x-elastic-client-meta
```

In my case, I forget to wrap the end of the line and thus get missing header error.

And this is the top search I got, so just put it here in case anyone made same mistake.